# Import module dynamic from a folder python

Tags: python, import

I have read other post about dynamic import of modules in python. And they work! The problem is when I am importing a module from a specific folder.
If I have the main python code and the module in the same folder:

main.py

module.py

If i do:

```
var = "module"
module = __import__(var)
```

It works great. But my module is in a specific folder named "modules"

main.py

modules\module.py

If I do:

```
var = "a"
module = __import__("modules\\"+var)
```

It doesn't work.
I know that I am pretty close of the solution but I can't get it.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming modules is indeed python package and var is your module name, you separate directory with dot.

```
var = "module" 
module = __import__("modules.{0}".format(var), globals(), locals(), [], -1)
```

You can check docs:

[**import** documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)

You to create an __init__.py file in your modules folder.

Comment: I haves this error: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe1' in file C:\modules\\__init__.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: I edited a question a little bit to be accurate with __import__. And about your error, really don't know what's inside your __init__.py. Try deleting everything and leave it empty.

Comment: I had to create __init__.py file in the modules folder and it works! Just create __init__.py empty. Thank you